# My GitHub webpage isn't available on the web

Tags: html, github, custom-error-pages

My GitHub page (https://visheshbons.github.io/cv/) isn't opening properly. All I get is this:

[image: Error 404]

I tried deleting the repository and remaking it so it would come but it just gave me error 404 anyway.

Can you please give me some solutions?

Thanks.
My problems are solved for HTML code, but my CSS isn't there. [Image-without-css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIhML.png)

Thanks! My problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

You have to publish your website, from your repository settings, go to "Pages"

[image: repo settings]

Then choose your branch and your root folder

[image: publish from branch]

then click on "Save" and wait for couple of minutes for your website to be published, then refresh the page to see your URL like this:

[image]

Comment: Check this "https://github.com/Visheshbons/cv/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages", it means that your website was deployed 3min ago. Now refresh your page, if you still see a 404 try doing a "hard reload" with Cmd+Shift+R

Comment: My CSS isn't available

Comment: The path for your CSS is wrong, it should be `CSS/styles.css` instead of `css/styles.css` (Use inspect element to see the result, and compare it to what you have in the repository)

Comment: Thanks, Fcmam5! you fixed my problem!